# PointAnimation without used triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want to use pointanimation on rectangle. I work in WPF. If i create storyboard and write only DoubleAnimation works. If I add PointAnimation system crash and write to me.

*The invocation of the constructor on type 'example.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'*

Is here option if this works without triggers and why this not work?

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Key="move">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"></DoubleAnimation>
    <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Center" To="100,100" Duration="0:0:2"></PointAnimation>
  </Storyboard>    
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: trigger is used to tell when to start the animation, if you dont want trigger when the animation should start? secondly is there exists a `Center` property of type `Point` in the rectangle or rect class?

Comment: @pushpraj In C# I write: `Storyboard a = this.Resources["move"] as Storyboard; a.Begin();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue with your storyboard is there is no `Center` property of type point which you can animate.

the actual error behind

`The invocation of the constructor on type 'example.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'`

is

`Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Center'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.`

below is an example using `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` to achieve similar behavior

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="move">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"></DoubleAnimation>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"></DoubleAnimation>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"></DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

**Setting location using PointAnimation example**

define a class with attached property to hold the value

```
class RectangleHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static Point GetLocation(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Point)obj.GetValue(LocationProperty);
    }

    public static void SetLocation(DependencyObject obj, Point value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(LocationProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Location.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Location", typeof(Point), typeof(RectangleHelper), new PropertyMetadata(new Point(), OnLocationChanged));


    private static void OnLocationChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point newValue = (Point)e.NewValue;

        d.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newValue.X);
        d.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newValue.Y);
    }
}
```

in the above code I am manipulating the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top on rectangle in the property change handler

then xaml as

```
<Storyboard x:Key="move">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="1" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"></DoubleAnimation>
    <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(l:RectangleHelper.Location)" To="100,100" Duration="0:0:2"></PointAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

I made example for Location, you may achieve Center with some calculations too.

Comment: So, here is PointAnimation useless?

Comment: Point animation can be used on supported properties only. if you still want point animation to work here you can make use of attached properties.